# Оптимальность кода

Tags: pascal, linq, pascalabc.net

Можно ли лучше написать этот код?

```
begin
  ReadArrString(ReadlnInteger('N:')).Select(x -> x.Chars[1] + '').Aggregate((a, b) -> a + b).JoinIntoString('').Println();
end.
```

Задача: Дана последовательность непустых строк. Используя метод Aggregate, получить строку, состоящую из начальных символов всех строк исходной последовательности.

Comment: Aggregate использовать принципиально?

Comment: Да, так как в задании сказано сделать именно так.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если использовать Aggregate принципиально — единственное, что здесь можно улучшить это использовать `StringBuilder` вместо кучи конкатенаций строк, в C# это будет выглядеть так (в pascal сами переведете):

```
s.Select(x => x[0]).Aggregate(new StringBuilder(), (sb, c) => sb.Append(c)).ToString();
```

Здесь s - входная коллекция строк.

Если Aggregate не принципиален, код получится короче при использовании конструктора `string`, принимающего массив `char`:

```
new string(s.Select(x => x[0]).ToArray());
```

Comment: Без Aggregate я бы решал так:
    begin
      Writeln(ReadlnInteger('N:').Range().Sum(x -> 1 / x));
    end.

Comment: Это на какую задачу ответ? Частичная сумма гармонического ряда? При чем тут вопрос из топика про начальные символы строк...

Comment: Извиняюсь, не тот код кинул.

begin
  Writeln(ReadArrString(ReadlnInteger('N:')).Sum(x -> x.Chars[1]));
end.

Comment: @VladislavMoldovan, в паскале это сработает? char+char даст string? Точно не int? Ну и что скажете на мой вариант всё-таки (на первый со StringBuilder)?

Comment: Да, сработает. Ваш вариант хороший. :)

Comment: Почему бы не отметить тогда его галочкой?

Comment: Уже отметил :).